# Segmentation fault in matrix multiplication using multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix, pthreads

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
int arr[1000][1000];
int brr[1000][1000];
int h;
int f;
void *BMM(void *arg)
{
    int* neo = (int*) arg;
    int ne = *neo;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        sum += arr[x][i]*brr[x][f];
        ++f;
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    crr[x][h] = sum;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
int main()
{
    pthread_t* ar = malloc(3*sizeof(*ar));
    printf("Enter the value of m and n\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
    for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Enter the value of p and q\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&p,&q);
    if(p != n)
    {
        printf("The matrix multiplication is not possible\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int* id;
    id = (int *)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < p; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < q; ++j)
        {
            scanf("%d",&brr[i][j]);
        }
    } 
    for(x = 0; x < m; ++x)
    {
        for(z = 0; z < q; z+=4)
        {
            f = z;
            h = z;
            for(int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
            {
                pthread_create(&ar[k],NULL,BMM,NULL);   
            }
            for(int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
            {
                pthread_join(ar[k],NULL);
            } 
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < q; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d ",crr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The above program is supposed to multiply two matrix by multiplying row one of matrix by all the columns of other matrix using 3 threads and then row two by all the other columns and so on and then store the respective values int another matrix but it is giving segmentation fault. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Not even trying to debug it?  Not even identifying where the segfault occurs?

Comment: What is `x`, where is it defined, and where is it set?

Comment: My bad I forgot to decalre x but as far as debuging is concerned I am  pretty sure that the error is in the part where I have created the threads or joined them because when I debugged the program the execution was not going at the function. But I don't know what is wrong there.

Comment: When asking for trouble-shooting of unexpected run-time behavior, you should post the actual code that actually compiles...

Comment: Note there is no check of the user's inputs and your matrix is statically allocated. This is a recipe for disaster because you can easilly write out of your matrix  bounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
pthread_create(&ar[k],NULL,BMM,NULL);   
                               ^^^^
                            void *arg is NULL
```

and then:

```
void *BMM(void *arg)
{
    int* neo = (int*) arg;
    int ne = *neo;             // Dereference NULL --> segmentation fault
```

Further this looks strange:

```
void *BMM(void *arg)
{
    int* neo = (int*) arg;
    int ne = *neo;           // ne is never used !! 
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)  // Where does n come from ?
```

Perhaps it should be `n` instead of `ne`?

If `n`, `x`, `f` and `h` are global variables you are into trouble as all threads will work on the same variables. That would be real bad. Each thread needs it own variables.

> BTW:

Always check the value returned by `scanf` - something like:

```
if (scanf("%d %d",&m,&n) != 2)
{
    // Add error handling here
}
```

and

```
if (scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]) != 1)
{
    // Add error handling here
}
```

Comment: I guess (because not shown) that OP is using globally defined variables `n` and `x` which are loop control variables in the calling function.

Comment: @WeatherVane - global variables... hmm - I guess you are right. That would however be real strange for a multi-thread implementation. Anyway, it doesn't change the fact that OP dereferences a NULL.